# Почему первая команда "mov saved_esp, esp"

Tags: ассемблер

Нашел такой код вируса Mumblehard на [opennet](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=42159).

Собственно первая команда "mov saved_esp, esp", а именно зачем передвигается указатель вершины стека и куда?

[image: изображение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока он никуда не передвигается насильно, а только запоминается текущее значение стека, что бы потом его можно было использовать. А как его потом используют, это вопрос к той части кода, которая не приведена. Вполне возможно, там потом используется выход в защищенный режим.